# Is AncestryDNA match of 1,655 cM a half sibling?

Tags: autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

> Shared DNA: 1,655 cM across 46 segments.

Can someone that shows this as one of my matches on AncestryDNA be a half sibling?

Answer (score 1):

Half-sibling is one of the possibilities. If you go to [The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1655), you 'll see that the full list of options include:

> Grandparent Aunt / Uncle Half Sibling Niece / Nephew Grandchild

You may be able to eliminate some of these if you know the age difference between the two matches.